# hibernate not saving the data to database

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {        
   Session s = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   Employ e = new Employ();
   e.setName("JoisCreaations");
   e.setId(2);
   Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
   try {       
     t.begin();
     s.save(e);
     t.commit();
   }
   catch(Exception ss) {              
     t.rollback();
   }
   finally {
     s.close();
   }

   PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
   out.println("SucesfullyAdded");

}
```

This is my code. Can someone tell me why it's not saving the data!!! there are no errors!! and everything is fine

I have even setup the config file and mapped everything correctly

Comment: Did you try `s.persist(e)` instead of `save(e)`?

Comment: You should watch the sql statement that is being done (enable hibernate debugging)

Comment: How do you know the data is not being saved?

Comment: and add ss.printStackTrace() in the catch clause

Comment: Is hibernate executing the sql statement you want? Try looking at it with hibernate.show_sql (here is the doc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional)

Comment: @LordAnomander i tried s.persist(e) it dint work

Comment: @andres i checked my database nothing was added

Comment: @leo i tried it too it doesnt make any difference

Comment: @GabrielIlharco thankyou for link but i could find the answer for my question so someone please help

Comment: Try adding `s.flush()` before `s.close()`

Comment: @GabrielIlharco i dint work

Comment: Try getting the session with this: 

`Configuration cfg=new Configuration();` 
`SessionFactory factory = cfg.configure().buildSessionFactory();`
`Session s = factory.openSession();`

Comment: @SumanthJois you realize that the advice leo gave you is not to make the code visible, but to be able to see a potential exception that is happening in your server logs, right?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Sumanth**

Try this code. I hope this will work for u.

```
@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    org.hibernate.Session ss = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = ss.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Employ e = new Employ();
        e.setName("JoisCreaations");
        e.setId(2);
        ss.save(e);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        ss.close();
    }
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.println("SucesfullyAdded");
}
```

Comment: it's not working!!! i am using derby database now?? shall i change to mysql and try?? does it make any difference?